# Problems with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Edited to include parent class...

I'm having problems changing state from a functional component using the useState hook. What am I doing wrong here? I've asterisked out my api key for this. locationOne and locationTwo are working great. Essentially this is a part of the app I'm making that takes a calculates the distance between two coordinates using the mapbox api.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { COORDS } from "./coords";

const CustomTrip = ({
  locationOne,
  locationTwo,
  onLocationOneChange,
  onLocationTwoChange
}) => {
  const [totalMiles, setTotalMiles] = useState(0);

  async function fetchDistance() {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api.mapbox.com/directions-matrix/v1/mapbox/driving/" +
        locationOne +
        ";" +
        locationTwo +
        "?sources=1&annotations=distance&access_token=****"
    );
    const mapBoxObject = await res.json();

    const meters = mapBoxObject.distances[0];
    const miles = parseInt(meters) * 0.00062137119;
    setTotalMiles(miles.toFixed(2));
    console.log(miles.toFixed(2));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDistance();
  }, [locationOne, locationTwo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <h1>Customize your trip</h1>
      </center>
      Select your starting point
      <select value={locationOne} onChange={onLocationOneChange}>
        {Object.entries(COORDS).map(([campus, longLatt]) => (
          <option key={campus} value={longLatt}>
            {campus}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      Select your destination
      <select value={locationTwo} onChange={onLocationTwoChange}>
        {Object.entries(COORDS).map(([campus, longLatt]) => (
          <option key={campus} value={longLatt}>
            {campus}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomTrip;
```

Here are the relevant bits of the parent class component:

```
class TippingPoint extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        totalMiles: 0,
        locationOne: '-97.4111604,35.4653761',
        locationTwo: '-73.778716,42.740913'       
      }



      this.onTotalMileChange.bind(this);
      this.onLocationOneChange.bind(this);
      this.onLocationTwoChange.bind(this);
    }  

    calculateTotals = () =>{ .... }



    onTotalMileChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({totalMiles: parseInt(event.target.value)},this.calculateTotals)    
    };

    onLocationOneChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({locationOne: event.target.value}, this.calculateTotals)
    }
    onLocationTwoChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({locationTwo: event.target.value}, this.calculateTotals)
    }

    render(){



                    <div>
                      <p>Trip Builder</p>

                          <CustomTrip totalMiles={this.state.totalMiles} locationOne={this.state.locationOne} 
                          locationTwo={this.state.locationTwo} onLocationOneChange={this.onLocationOneChange} 
                          onLocationTwoChange={this.onLocationTwoChange} onTotalMileChange={this.onTotalMileChange}/>

                    </div>


  export default TippingPoint;
```

Comment: what output are you getting for the `console.log`?

Comment: For the last two coordinates I chose I got 1357.39

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? You don't appear to use `totalMiles` anywhere

Comment: I'm using totalMiles in a class component, shall I attach it too?

Comment: State can be used by the component or passed to children (or parent in callback). What is `totalMiles` supposed to be used for? Is that the issue that some `totalMiles` somewhere else isn't being updated?

Comment: I perform calculations on totalMiles in a class component to get estimates for how expensive it is to travel between two points on a map. The issue is that I'm not seeing totalMiles change when I look at the state in the react chrome extension... but I am seeing it changer under hooks? I just need that number passed back to my class component.

Comment: Is the class component a parent of CustomTrip?

Comment: Yes it is a parent if CustomTrip

Comment: @JoshWren Then I'd say that this code doesn't belong in this Component but the parent Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like you need to also pass a callback for `CustomTrip` to call in order to pass `totalMiles` back to a parent component. There is also now no need to temporarily store `totalMiles` in state, it can be passed directly in the callback.

```
const CustomTrip = ({
  locationOne,
  locationTwo,
  onLocationOneChange,
  onLocationTwoChange,
  onTotalMilesComputed
}) => {
  async function fetchDistance() {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api.mapbox.com/directions-matrix/v1/mapbox/driving/" +
        locationOne +
        ";" +
        locationTwo +
        "?sources=1&annotations=distance&access_token=****"
    );
    const mapBoxObject = await res.json();

    const meters = mapBoxObject.distances[0];
    const miles = parseInt(meters) * 0.00062137119;

    onTotalMilesComputed(miles.toFixed(2)); // <-- passed callback
    console.log(miles.toFixed(2));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDistance();
  }, [locationOne, locationTwo]);

...
```

Parent component now just needs a handler for it. (*If parent is functional component make `onTotalMilesComputed` const and omit the `this.`*)

```
onTotalMilesComputed = totalMilage => {
  // do something with totalMilage, like set/update state
}

...

render() {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <CustomTrip
      // ...all other passed props, locations, etc...
      onTotalMilesComputed={this.onTotalMilesComputed}
    />
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: what would the handler look like? I'm stuck on writing that now.

Comment: @JoshWren Added *an implementation* of a callback in the parent to my answer.

Comment: I actually have a change handler for totalMiles that I use with other computations in the parent component and when I use that like you've demonstrated I get "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" my change handler is:

Comment: onTotalMileChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({totalMiles: parseInt(event.target.value)},this.calculateTotals)    
    };

Comment: @JoshWren Well, your `onTotalMileChange` takes an event object, not a computed "total mileage" value. `fetchDistance` is also an async function, which means it implicitly returns a promise, so anything calling it should potentially handle promise rejections. `fetchDistance` function assumes happy path, so if anything you are processing throws an error it'll propagate up the call stack until it is caught. `Fetch` returns a Promise but it won't reject upon error, but extracting the JSON data *could* throw if fetch returns failed fetch, you should check `res.ok` first.

Comment: @JoshWren At this point it may be more beneficial to update your question to include these bits of the parent component so it is clearer what the relationship is between the two components.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is the issue faced by you. But as far as useState is concerned, try putting it after import statement, outside CustomTrip declaration.

Comment: [Only Call Hooks from React Functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, just a suggesgion:

This function doesn't feel as it belongs *inside* the Component. It's basically a pure function; takes some arguments and returns a result. And, at least I hope that, always the same result for the same arguments

```
async function fetchDistance(locationOne, locationTwo) {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://api.mapbox.com/directions-matrix/v1/mapbox/driving/" +
      locationOne +
      ";" +
      locationTwo +
      "?sources=1&annotations=distance&access_token=****"
  );
  const mapBoxObject = await res.json();

  const meters = mapBoxObject.distances[0];
  const miles = parseInt(meters) * 0.00062137119;

  console.log(miles.toFixed(2));
  return miles.toFixed(2);
}
```

and inside the Component you just do:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchDistance(locationOne, locationTwo).then(setTotalMiles);
}, [locationOne, locationTwo]);
```

This may also help you move this logic into the parent Component, as I don't think it belongs in the one you show. 
The Component in your snippet is merely a controlled input to get the two locations. It has no state and no logic to do anything but get the two locations and forward them to the parent component.

So why should it contiain the logic to compute the distance of two props that are given to it, just to "return" the result back to the component that provided the props? Without even using that computed value in any way.